# Passing constexpr const char* to template function?

Tags: c++, printf, c++17, constexpr

Im trying to wrap a printf like function while preserving the warning you get for invalid format (MSVC doesn't allow extending this to your own printf functions..).

Example here:

https://godbolt.org/z/na_JOe

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

#include <stdio.h>

#pragma warning(error : 4477)


constexpr const char* t = "%s";

template<typename... Args>
void test_tpl(Args&&... args) {

        constexpr size_t optimistic_buffer_size = 1024;
        static thread_local char optimistic_buffer[optimistic_buffer_size];

        int ret_count = _snprintf(optimistic_buffer, optimistic_buffer_size, t, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

}



int main() {
    std::string hello;
    test_tpl(hello);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works (fires the warning as it should).

**However the issue is to make the format string a parameter while preserving the invalid format warning**

The following *naive* approach is invalid syntax:

```
template<typename... Args>
void test_tpl(constexpr const char* format, Args&&... args) {
```

Now this works if the string is constexpr - it *feels like* this should be easy enough to turn into a parameter (although im aware it may not be) ? but is there some simpel way or trick here I can benefit from ?

Comment: Please paste code into the question. (Also providing a link is okay.) It makes it easier for people to help, and sometimes external links die.

Comment: What do you mean with "this works if the string is constexpr"? A string can't be a constexpr. Do you mean it works, when you replace `test_tpl(hello);` with `test_tpl(t);`? This is because you can't pass `std::string` as first argument to printf.

Comment: To avoid the "invalid format", you have to pass a `chat const *`, not a `std::string`, given that the format is `"%s"`. So the call should be `test_tpl(hello.c_str());`

Comment: @churill see my update

Comment: Should work if you call `test_tpl(hello.c_str());`, I think.

Comment: @churill that isn't the issue here

Comment: I think, _now_ I understand. You want to keep the compiler warnings about wrong format in printf while using a wrapper like this, right?

Comment: gcc has `__attribute__ ((format (printf, 2, 3)));` for that. It seems there is no equivalent for msvc :-/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly... you want to pass the format as argument mantaining the compiler warning about the wrong format...

The only way I see is pass the format as template parameter.

Something as follows

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

#include <cstdio>

constexpr char const t[] = "%s";

template <char const * frmt, typename ... Args>
void test_tpl (Args && ... args)
 {
   constexpr size_t optimistic_buffer_size = 1024;
   static char optimistic_buffer[optimistic_buffer_size];

   snprintf(optimistic_buffer, optimistic_buffer_size, frmt,
            std::forward<Args>(args)...);
 }

int main ()
 {
   std::string hello;

   test_tpl<t>(hello);
 }
```

Comment: This way, it doesn't seem to fire the warning

Comment: @darune - It's a pity; g++ fire the warning and clang++ fire an error (about the wrong format).